# centos server running cakephp can't access remote mysql server but can access via pdo connect outside of cake

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I asked this on stackexchange also but its starting to look more like a programming issue instead of configuration

centos server running cakephp can't access remote mysql server but can access via pdo connect outside of cake

I can connect using the mysql commandline client using the same credentials and options. however when cake tries to connect to the remote server all I get is

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'subdomian.domain.com' (13) requires a database connection
```

I tried running this

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myrootuser'@'webserver.domain.com' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This won't help me because I know I can connect via the cli

I can connect remotely from my home computers cake instance with no problems same host same credentials same everything

Yet my centos apache server running cake with all the right mysql packages installed can't connect

I am using the correct username password port everything and I keep getting that error

I have cleared tmp folders cache I used apc to clear cache I even restarted httpd

I have done everything. Nothing works.

I have event tried temporarily shutting off the firewall on both machines... no dice same error

I even tried creating a php file that just uses pdo to connect to the db and running it from the command line and it says Connected to Database !!

Why can't cake do it from cake. It can obviously work from a lone php file

I verified my creds and host over and over again

again I am able to connect using the exact same codebase on my local machine

so there has to be something like a mystery cake or centos apache thing going

I am also running APC Restarting mysqld and httpd doesn't change anything. I am at my wits end with this nonsense.

this is the php script I am testing with

```
$hostname = "my.dns.name.tohost";
$username = "myrootuser";
$password = "myrootuserpass";

try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=myDbSchemaName", $username, $password);
  echo "Connected to database";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

// console output

```
Connected to database[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# php connectInt.php
Connected to database[root@localhost ~]#
```

So I am like cool lets go try to site again.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'subdomian.domain.com' (13) requires a database connection
```

nothing works

I even tried other ways in php I did a normal mysql connect script using the same credentails it can connect it can see all the databases.

```
<?php
$hostname = "dns.name.com";
$username = "mygoodtestednonrootuser";
$password = "somepasswoerd";

try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=int_zzipline", $username, $password);

$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list))
{
    echo 'Connected to database';
    echo $row->Database . "\n";
}   

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>


[root@localhost ~]# php connectInt.php
information_schema
mydbname1
myotherdb
mysql
test
```

So I am like cool lets go try the site again

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'subdomian.domain.com' (13) requires a database connection
```

This is infuriating to say the least.

So cakephp doesn't like to connect to other linux servers in the same subnet without any firewall turned on yet any other php executed with the same credentials works. my local pc running the exact same code base talking to the same server works.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the details properly in your database.php? Cake doesn't do any magic to prevent you from connecting to non-local databases. Here's the connection code btw. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L130

Comment: Thank ADmad, but that is covered in the descriptions. I did say the same code base could connect on other servers and through normal php run from the command line. Alas. SELINUX was the issue the whole time. When they say "SECURITY ENHANCED" man they really mean it.

Answer (score 2):

SELINUX was the culprit. As soon as I disabled it and rebooted everything was fine. I was running my web virtual host in /opt to help with obfuscation but it appears the biggest pain in my you know what the whole time with simple stuff like giving apache write access to logs, uploads, everything was because of SELINUX. It even was preventing cake from talking to a database it could talk to with no problems otherwise.

I knew centos was secure as a boss, but now I know why. SELINUX

learn about it, what it does and discover a world where centos no longer wants to be stubborn SELinux is CentOS's his little friend that will cover your ass instead of busting your balls.

With power comes great responsibility. When I get over beating myself up about this I will begin the work of reconfiguring my server to use SELINUX responsibly instead of using it without knowing why I am using it. Oh and of course the solution:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
#SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Oh I almost forgot.... **You can find the config file in /ect/selinux**

just change yours to look like this and you should be able to do any ol thing you please. but so will the h4x0rz

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was really a life saver as I didn't find this fix anywhere and that was the error which I would have never been able to fix if you hadn't posted it here. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.